# Oscillations concept about velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

For a SHM the velocity increases as the object goes from one extreme position  to the mean position, then decreases from the mean position to other extreme position. Is this increase and decrease symmetrical?
What I mean to ask is that whether the velocity when the object is x units to the right of m.p same as the velocity when it x units to the left of the m.p.

Comment: Try to write velocity as a function of the position "x", you will see the graph of v^2  and x^2  turns out to be a standard ellipse. This tells us about the symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a SHM, the total energy $E$ stays constant and is made up of kinetic and potential energy:
$$ E = E_{kin}+E_{pot}=\frac{1}{2} mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx^2 $$
Therefore, the velocity is given by
$$v = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}-\frac{kx^2}{m}}$$
This is clearly symmetric in $x$, i.e., $v(x)=v(-x)$. Therefore, yes, the velocity (or more precisely, the absolute value of the velocity) at a length right of the mean point (i.e., zero) is the same as the velocity left of it. The sign of the velocity depends on the current direction (i.e., is the mass just going towards the extreme position or is it coming back from the extreme position).

Answer (score 3):

A quick footnote to Sanya's answer. To simplify the algebra we'll use the boundary condition that the displacement is zero at time zero, in which case the equation of motion of our simple harmonic oscillator is:

$$ x(t) = x_0 \sin(\omega t) \tag{1} $$

The velocity is obtained by differentiating this with respect to time:

$$ v(t) = \frac{d}{dt}x(t) = x_0 \omega \cos(\omega t) \tag{2}$$

The trouble is that you asked if the velocity was symmetric in $x$, and we have it as a function of time. To convert it to a function of $x$ we note that:

$$ \cos(\omega t) = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2(\omega t)} $$

and from equation (1) we have $\sin(\omega t) = x/x_0$, so we get:

$$ \cos(\omega t) = \pm\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^2} $$

And substituting in equation (2) gives:

$$ v(t) = \pm\, x_0 \omega \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^2} \tag{3}$$

And since we only have $x^2$ on the right hand side this means $|v(x)| = |v(-x)|$ and therefore that the motion is symmetrical.

Equation (3) is actually the same equation that Sanya derived using only conservation of energy (and a lot less effort, so do it Sanya's way!). If we rearrange (3) to take the $x_0 \omega$ inside the square root we get:

$$ v(t) = \pm\, \sqrt{x_0^2 \omega^2  - x^2\omega^2} $$

You need to know that the total energy is:

$$ E = \tfrac{1}{2}kx_0^2 $$

and the angular freqency is:

$$ \omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} $$

And substituting these gives us Sanya's expression:

$$ v = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}-\frac{kx^2}{m}} $$

Which proves mainly that is always a hard way to derive any equation :-)

Answer (score 1):

The velocity $v$ of an object at a position $x$ from equilibrium undergoing simple harmonic motion of amplitude $A$ and angular frequency $\omega\; (= 2\pi \times \rm frequency)$ is given by the equation

$$v^2=\omega^2(A^2-x^2)$$

If the velocity $v$ is plotted against the position $x$ an ellipse which is symmetrical about the origin is generated showing the speeds of the  particle at positions $\pm x$ are the same.

[image]